# Android: ListView selected item (onClick) stay selected after action

Tags: android, listview, arraylist, selection

I have a problem with my ListView. If I click an item, this item is highlighted (this is ok) and another activity starts to edit details or to delete a dataset. After coming back to my list the item is still selected, even if it is no longer available...

```
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Xi1z.png">
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/JaqCP.png">
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/p3OAU.png">
here should be some pictures that i cannot insert unfortunately because the editor thinks it is code ...
```

Only if I use the back-narrow (left of "Vertrag) the item is no longer highlighted. If I use another menu item the item stays highlighted. Also if I use the FloatingActionButton the item in my list stays highlighted.

How can I remove this highlighting? I already tried clearChoices() in different ways but it did not work.

My fragment_list.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/fragment_list"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".ContractList">

<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:divider="@color/colorListDivider"
    android:dividerHeight="@dimen/divider_height"
    android:listSelector="@color/colorListSelected"
    android:cacheColorHint="@color/colorListcacheColorHint"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="false" />

<TextView
    android:id="@android:id/empty"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/nodata"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    android:background="@color/colorListEmptyBackground" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**EDIT: - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -**

I got the **solution**:
I set

```
android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"
```

and created an drawable xml file list_selector.xml with

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_pressed="false"
    android:state_selected="false"
    android:drawable="@color/colorListBackground" />
<item android:state_pressed="true">
    <shape>
        <gradient
            android:startColor="@color/colorListSelected"
            android:endColor="@color/colorListSelected"
            android:angle="270" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item android:state_pressed="false"
    android:state_selected="true"
    android:drawable="@color/colorListBackground" />
</selector>
```

So the list item highlights with my custom color and does not stay highlighted after selection.

Comment: use runnable method and after selection (about 200 millisecond) remove the high light

Comment: What is the use of this line `listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(android.R.id.list);` ?

Comment: ListView defines my ListView in my layout file. But I think I don't need that line, that's right.

Comment: @Assem Mahrous, where should I insert the runnable and how to remove the highlight? Manually overwriting the color?

Comment: in your list check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please remove this from your fragment_xml's listview: `android:listSelector="@color/colorListSelected"`

or use

`android:listSelector="?attr/selectableItemBackground"` instead

and if it does not work, you may like to use your own custom style.

Comment: can you please provide your `ContractListFragment`'s layout and code?

Comment: I added fragment_list.xml, list.xml and my array adapter in my post above

Comment: Please remove this from your fragment_xml's listview: `android:listSelector="@color/colorListSelected"` or use `android:listSelector="?attr/selectableItemBackground"` instead

Comment: @yvi, Did that help you?

Comment: It worked but then I have a default highlight color. I'll try to use a custom style. Thanks!

Comment: I edited my answer, if you find it useful, you may like to up vote it. Thanks

Comment: I found a solution an appended it to my question